# What would be an effective way to update templates for a CMS?

Tags: php, templates

I'm a developer for a CMS system my employer sells to customers. We use PHP and MySQL. The CMS admin panel includes an update system to keep the CMS up to date with each new version released. We are in the process of developing a variety of standard of custom templates for the CMS, all using Smarty.

The conundrum we are facing is how to update these templates as new versions of the CMS are released.

We are aware that many users of the CMS will greatly customize their templates and updating the templates will overwrite them, but template updates are often necessary when we add new features to the CMS. Does anyone have any ideas regarding a template update methodology?

Comment: Templates are there to provide a layer of independence from the underlying engine. package your templates seperately from the engine so that customers can upgrade only the parts they want.

Comment: Is this software you are selling or something you are hosting? This is basically a VCS problem ... when you are updating your templates, you could just use `patch` to apply the diffs, and if there's a conflict with a user change, flag it for manual merge. Clobbering your users' templates would not be ideal from a customer perspective. Other CMS like eZPublish allow individual template files to be [overridden](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.8/Templates/The-template-override-system) in a flexible way so there's never any need to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as a Wordpress developer, any customizations I make are done not on the delivered CSS or PHP but new files.  It is common knowledge among seasoned developers that as new templates are rolled out that customizations done on the delivered files are overwritten.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? If a template consists of a few CSS files and a bunch of TPL files, how would you handle that?

Comment: Sure Christopher, the developer needs to add another CSS file that contains their customizations. You would not need to know about the name, mine I usually call custom.css. That way when you opt to upgrade your CSS template, I still have my own private CSS which is read first - and therefore all my customizations overwrite yours. Does this make sense?